# return whole column of tab separated csv file that has grep match

Tags: regex, linux, csv, command-line, grep

Lets say I have a tab separated csv file as below:

```
a b c  
d e f  
g h i
```

Using commandline utilities, is there a way I could return the whole column that matches a required grep pattern or in the above example, I would like to return the second column for a grep of b?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 awk -F'\t' -v pat="b" 'NR==FNR{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i~pat)c[i];next}
                        {s="";for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
                         if(i in c)s=s sprintf("%s\t", $i);
                         sub(/\t$/,"",s);print s}' file file
```

this line does the job.

- it will print any columns that matches your `pat`, and keep in `column` format.
- the `pat` is regex, you can pass a shell variable to the awk line
- the output follow the original column order

take a look the example: (I add a `b` in your 3rd column to show multiple matching case):

```
kent$  cat f
a       b       c
d       e       b
g       h       i

kent$  awk -F'\t' -v pat="b" 'NR==FNR{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i~pat)c[i];next}{s="";for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if(i in c)s=s sprintf("%s\t", $i);sub(/\t$/,"",s);print s}' f f
b       c
e       b
h       i
```

Answer (score 1):

If there is just a matching, you can do for example this:

```
$ awk -v patt="b" 'FNR==NR {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) $i~patt && col=i; next} {print $col}' file file
b
e
h
```

#### Explanation

It loops twice through the file. Firstly to get the column number of the matched text. Secondly to print that specific column.

- `-v patt="b"` give the pattern
- `FNR==NR {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) $i~patt && col=i; next}` on the first read, loop through fields and check if the pattern is matched. If so, store the column number in the `col` var.
- `{print $col}` print that specific col of all lines.

Answer (score 0):

You really need to give a hint how big your files are, how often you want to run this, and how many columns you have. But

1. grep is fast(er than awk)
2. unless your files are huge, they are likely to be cached (so it is OK to read them twice)

Based on the observations above, I would

1. grep the file for the pattern (pipe the result to uniq if needed)
2. calculate which columns are needed from grep's output
3. run awk with -vCOLS="c1 c2 c3..." and a trivial script which prints the columns specified by c1, c2...

Comment: the files I am working with are of the order of 1K-2K